# Computational complexity of Lodash functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, time-complexity, lodash, memory-consumption

I've tried to found on Lodash website and on the web informations about time and memory complexity of Lodash functions, especially get, but I didn't manage to get anything.
Is anybody know something about it ?

Thanks !

NB: Since lodash is open source, I can do it myself if necessary ^^

Answer (score 0):

A jsperf example can be helpful for your use case. [This link](http://jsperf.com/pick-native-vs-underscore-vs-lodash) is a possible one here which tests the performance on browsers for the native vs the underscrore function and lodash methods.

Here are other methods test

[Filter](https://jsperf.com/prime-vs-underscore-vs-lodash/3)

[ForEach Loop](https://jsperf.com/lodash-vs-underscore-vs-native-js-foreach-loops)

[Pluck](https://jsperf.com/pluck-underscore-vs-lodash-vs-custom/3)

[Map](https://jsperf.com/map-underscore-vs-jquery/3)

And as for the memory consumtion you can always use chrome tools to capture heat map and heap memory deumps .

Comment: @DGallet I believe 'This link' shows that native is more performant. The graph is based on `Operations per second (higher is better)`

Comment: You’re perfectly right, this comment had no sense, I remove it right away !